# How to add a WSS entry in Soap UI using Groovy scripting

Tags: groovy, soapui

How do i add WSS entry in SoapUI using groovy scripting.

I want to add a Signature type of a WSS entry as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: If you are sing soap request thru SOAP request test step, those details are automatically added in the header on the fly. What is your use case?

Comment: Already head a look at the repository code to see how to get aroundin WSS? Don't know about WSS, but you can find the package here: https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui/tree/0f5e49cfff2a91a75694c36fb1c04883de2056de/soapui/src/main/java/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/support/wss. This site has been a major source of information for my scripts to update headers with a custom UI, collecting info to create HTML reports and so on.